# Should we create instance of EasyTracker multime times when trying to send logs to Google Analytics dashboard

Tags: android, google-analytics, easytracker

I am using Google Analytics in android project. For this wherever I'm sending analytics I'm creating object of `EasyTracker` class.

Suppose user is on First Activity then I'm creating the object of `EasyTracker` in `onCreate` so when user navigate to second activity then again I'm creating object of `EasyTracker` in `onCreate` of second activity.

Should we create object of `EasyTracker` once only and use it same in entire application or this does not matter. I guess that by creating two object of `EasyTracker` Google Analytics is assuming that there are two real time users but exact is only one.

```
EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(ActivityMain.this);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at sample:

```
  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ... // The rest of your onStart() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  // Add this method.
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ... // The rest of your onStop() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
  }
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/

It seems that EasyTracker is singletone and you should call getInstance every time.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider switching to a newer v4 version of the Google Analytics SDK for Android. v4 of the API support automatic activity reporting - [Tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker.html#enableAutoActivityTracking(boolean)). Once you enable automatic tracking it does the screen reporting for you. Easy tracker is v2/v3 of the API and doesn't support many new features added to Google Analytics like demographics reporting. Google only maintains the latest version of the SDK so v2/v3 might not work that well on newer versions of Android.